# Android use internal mic and bluetooth headset as speaker with high quality media protocol during calls

Tags: android, audio, bluetooth, headset

I have bluetooth earbuds with great sound quality and built-in microphones. In my android bluetooth device settings, I have to switches for media profiles: 'Call audio' and 'media audio'

Behavier with both activated:

- when mic not needed: high quality sound protocol (1-directional, phone to headset)
- when mic needed: switches to low quality sound protocol (2-directional, headset mic also streamed to phone)

Problem: I want better audio quality during calls, because I often am on long calls (mostly on discord) and I want to listen to music in the background with great quality.

Therefore I want to use the 1-directional great protocol and the internal built-in microphone

I did some testing using the audio recorder at first:

- turned off 'Call audio' switch in bluetooth settings
- earbuds not recognized as possible microphone
- recording startet, music on earbuds paused, internal mic was being recorded, I could listen to music in great quality (had to hit play again) on my earbuds with great quality simultaneously -> perfect

So I thought I discoverd the solution, BUT:
On Discord (or any other call app) the earbuds did not show up as a possible speaker.
When listing to music on the earbuds and then joining a call, the audio output immediatly switched to the speaker/earpiece speaker (call audio and music). Probably because the call profile was disabled.

Does anyone have a solution/workaround?

- sure, wired headphones would work
- Maybe there is a way to redirect my call output from discord to a media stream and then into my earbuds (Then the voice quality on discord would not improve, but I could listen to music in high quality). I found an app (BTmono) doing basically the oppsite for headsets with a call profile only: It converts your media output into a mono stream and outputs it as call audio
- maybe, I can somehow mark my earbud's media profile as a call profile too

or maybe anyone got some other workaround that did not come to my mind yet.

I would really appreciate a proper solution to my problem, thanks